# Permission denied on executable, as root

Tags: permissions, centos, executable

When I attempt to run a bash script as root, I get permission denied:

```
[root@boxen test3]# ll
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root webdev 172 Jul 24 15:30 printdate.sh

[root@boxen test3]# ./printdate.sh 
-bash: ./printdate.sh: Permission denied
```

Here are the containing folder permissions:

```
[root@boxen test3]# namei -l /www/virtualhosts/test3/
f: /www/virtualhosts/test3/
dr-xr-xr-x root   root   /
drwxr-xr-x root   root   www
drwxrwx--- apache webdev virtualhosts
drwxrwxrwx apache webdev test3
```

What's causing the permissions error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that the volume was mounted with noexec.   I temporarily remounted with

```
mount -o remount,exec /www/
```

did my work, then set the noexec back in place.

Comment: I had no idea that was even a thing! In my case, I just moved it. But, this worked